# Mssql node, input value to request

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular

I am using angular2 and `mssql` to connect to SQL Server.

This is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'EnakAja123',
    server: '192.168.1.37', 
    database: 'Angular' 
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    next();
});

app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.input('username', req.body.username) <<
        request.input('password', req.body.password) <<
        request.query('select * from Angular_user where username = @username and password = @password', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

How can I insert a value to this request.body.username and password?

Because I don't know how this request and response works

Answer (score 1):

You should use `body-parser` with `express` to parse the request boy. Check [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) documentation and [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#express-route-specific).